# Why does Bluetoothapis on Windows fail to detect whether an iPhone is connected?

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth

I've written this code to automatically lock Windows when the phone's Bluetooth isn't connected. However, deviceInfo.fConnected doesn't seem to accurately detect whether the iPhone is connected. It works when I use my headphones.
Here is the code:

```
void autolock(const wchar_t* deviceName){
    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS searchParams = {
            sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS),
            0,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
    };

    BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo;
    deviceInfo.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);
    const wchar_t* headPhone = deviceName;

    int cnt =0;
    while(true)
    {

        std::cout << cnt++ << std::endl;
        HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND hFind = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&searchParams, &deviceInfo);
        if (hFind != NULL) {
            do {
                // Check if the device is connected
                int i = wcscmp(deviceInfo.szName,headPhone);
                if (!deviceInfo.fConnected && i == 0) {
                    LockWorkStation();
                }
            } while (BluetoothFindNextDevice(hFind, &deviceInfo));
            BluetoothFindDeviceClose(hFind);
        }
        Sleep(3000);

    }
}
```

I would like to know if there are any alternative APIs or methods available. I couldn't find any information on Google, and GPT can't help me.

Comment: This method works only for your device is classic one. For LE connection it does not work. Also you can simple handle HCI connect/disconnect events for your device to know when it connects and disconnects.